# cvs2git was creating some extra commits while migrating CVS to Git

Tags: cvs2git, git-fast-import

The following commit message showing while migrating from CVS to Gitlab using cvs2git (Python 2.7.5). While migrating I noticed that cvs2svn was creating some extra commits with same following message that seem to be unnecessary.

Why its creating unwanted commits during migration?

```
  This commit was manufactured by cvs2svn to create branch 'BRANCH_DEV_2014'.
```

Answer (score 2):

CVS allows you to tag/branch some subset of all files. Or tag/branch different versions of files that existed at different times. (You could in theory create a tag that only tagged half of your files and of those, 1/3 could have been the versions from 2003 and the other 2/3 the versions from 2019.)

This can be intentional, or unintentional just because CVS is a bit messy that way.

Git, on the other hand, enforces that all tags/branches are created on a specific consistent state of the repository from a single point in time.

In the cvs2git process, when creating a tag/branch, if the tool cannot find any specific point in time and state of the whole repo that represents this new tag/branch, cvs2git will create a dummy commit to allow it to then tag/branch.

---

Example:

If you have two files in CVS, a.class and a_test.class and you have three commits to both of the

1. a.class a_test.class --- Initial version
2. a.class a_test.class --- Commit 2
3. a.class a_test.class --- Commit 3

And then you created a tag `v.1.0.0` based on Commit 2, *except* you only tagged a.class, you did not tag a_test.class.

When you convert this to git, git has no way to handle this, so it has to create a dummy commit.

```
o - Initial commit
|
o - Commit 2
|\ 
|  o - Dummy commit, removes a_test.class so there's just a.class. Tagged v.1.0.0
|
o - Commit 3
```